# Downcast protocol conformance in extension

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say I have two **non-generi**c protocols **(1)**

```
protocol StringValue {
    var asString: String {get}
}

protocol StringProvider {
    var value: StringValue {get}
}
```

I want to have a **generic** version of the second one **(2)**

```
protocol TypedStringProvider: StringProvider { // inherits from StringProvider
    associatedtype TypedStringValue: StringValue
    var typedValue: TypedStringValue { get }
}
```

And extension with default implementation of non-generic version to have a code free conformance to `StringProvider` (**doesn't work**, pls read below)  **(3)**

```
extension TypedStringProvider { 
    var value: TypedStringValue { return typedValue }
}
```

Now I want **several** classes to conform **both** generic `TypedStringProvider` and non-generic `StringProvider` protocols **(4)**

```
extension UIView: TypedStringProvider {
    typealias TypedStringValue = String
    var typedValue: String { return "Some String" }
}

extension Double: TypedStringProvider {
    typealias TypedStringValue = String
    var typedValue: String { return String(self) }
}

extension String: StringValue {
    var asString: String { return self }
}
```

And get compiler error: `Type 'UIView' does not conform to protocol 'StringProvider'`.

Seemingly extension (3) doesn't work like I want because `TypedStringValue` is not a `StringValue` in despite of this constraint `associatedtype TypedStringValue: StringValue` from (2)

**The question is** how to conform to non-generic `StringProvider` while keeping `value` typed

**Example**:

```
0.5.value.lowercased()
```

Of course `StringValue` doesn't have `lowercased` method from `String` so it won't compile.

**What I have tried:**

**First** is to add untyped property to extension (3)

```
extension TypedStringProvider {
    var value: TypedStringValue { return typedValue }
    var value: StringValue { return typedValue }
}
```

Doesn't work because of `Invalid redeclaration of 'value'` error

**Second** is to extend my classes and add untyped property there **(5)**

```
extension UIView {
    var value: StringValue { return typedValue }
}

extension Double {
    var value: StringValue { return typedValue }
}
```

**It works** without compiler errors **but**

1. No autocompletion for `lowercased` in our example.
2. With extensions (5) I need to write a lot of code for every class conforming `StringProvider` and every property this protocol has

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution

```
extension StringProvider where Self: TypedStringProvider {
    var value: StringValue { return typedValue }
}
```

With this extension there's no need to write similar extensions to every class and autocompletion works too.

Full code:

```
protocol StringValue {
    var asString: String {get}
}

protocol StringProvider {
    var value: StringValue {get}
}

protocol TypedStringProvider: StringProvider {
    associatedtype TypedStringValue: StringValue
    var typedValue: TypedStringValue { get }
}

extension StringProvider where Self: TypedStringProvider {
    var value: StringValue { return typedValue }
}

extension TypedStringProvider {
    var value: TypedStringValue { return typedValue }
}

extension UIView: TypedStringProvider {
    typealias TypedStringValue = String
    var typedValue: String { return "some string" }
}

extension Double: TypedStringProvider {
    typealias TypedStringValue = String
    var typedValue: String { return String(self) }
}

extension String: StringValue {
    var asString: String { return self }
}

let doubleValue = 0.5.value.lowercased()
```

Answer (score 0):

`value` is defined as type `StringValue`, so this is the type you should specify in your extension of `TypedStringProvider` in order to complete the protocol conformance:

```
extension TypedStringProvider {
    var value: StringValue {
        return typedValue
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know. I wrote it under (4). But the problem here that I need a typed property to call it's methods.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

On `StringProvider` you are defining `value` to a `StringValue`:

```
protocol StringProvider {
    var value: StringValue { get }
}
```

but here you are defining the type to `TypedStringValue` which is not the same as `StringValue`. (underlying value can be `TypedStringValue`, however it needs to be typecasted from `StringValue` to `TypedStringValue` when using it)

```
extension TypedStringProvider { 
    var value: TypedStringValue { return typedValue }
}
```

### Solution

There are two solutions that I can come up for this scenario right now:

#### 1. Generic Approach

If you want to make `value` generic and change the type based on `TypedStringProvider` you can:

```
protocol StringProvider {
    associatedtype StringProviderValue: StringValue
    var value: StringProviderValue { get }
}
```

Conform to the protocol by defining `StringProviderValue` to `TypedStringValue`

```
extension TypedStringProvider {
    var value: TypedStringValue { return typedValue }
}
```

#### 2. StringValue approach

Keep the `StringProvider` as it is:

```
protocol StringProvider {
    var value: StringValue { get }
}
```

Conform to the protocol by using the correct `StringValue` type, and inside it return `typedValue: TypedStringValue` which can be downcasted to `StringValue`

```
extension TypedStringProvider {
    var value: StringValue { return typedValue }
}
```

### Output

Both solutions give the same output:

[image]

Comment: Maybe my description was not quite clear but I want 2 things:
1. Keep `StringProvider` non-generic (why do I have generic TypedStringProvider?) 
2. Keep `value` typed (TypedStringValue, not a StringValue)